# How to Split an Array list which is then output into a combobox

Tags: java, arrays, combobox

I am currently passing an array list created in another Class (ClassA) into another Class (ClassB) using a method in ClassA called getList().

```
public List<Doctor> doctorList = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
```

The array above creates an ArrayList which stores the doctors' details such as name and medical discipline.

```
public  List<Doctor> getList()
    {

        return doctorList; 
    }
```

I then use Class B to populate a combo box however it populates it fine but the content of the array list is stored all in one line, I want to split this so that i am then able to select a specific doctor.

```
public void loadArray()
{

ClassA im = new ClassA();
im.getList();

     cmboDoctorList.addItem(im.getList());

}
```

Comment: Seems like you need to `addItem` for each element in the `ArrayList`. Search for "iterating through ArrayList"

It is more useful if you can provide a complete example of your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the list as an item loop through the list and add each item.

```
for (Doctor doc : im.getList()) {
    cmboDoctorList.addItem(doc);
}
```

Comment: how can i get a specific variable within this arraylist. for example, If I only want the name of the doctor.

Comment: assuming the name has a getter you can do.  cmboDoctorList.addItem(doc.getName());